# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

estoy aprendiendo a hacer una tabla dinámica que me muestre los valores extraídos desde una base de datos, el problema es que al ejecutar me dice :

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:...

y creo que el error se origina en:

$consulta="SELECT * FROM registro WHERE (Nombre_Usuario = '$nombre')";

pero no estoy seguro.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Mi Web</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    include 'link.php';

    
        $nombre  =$_POST['user'];
        $password =$_POST['pass'];
        $fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
       
        
        
        $insert_usuario = "INSERT INTO usuario (nombre,clave) VALUES ('$nombre','$password')";
        $insert_registro = "INSERT INTO registro (Fecha,Nombre_Usuario) VALUES ('$fecha','$nombre')";

        mysqli_query($conexion,$insert_usuario);
        
        mysqli_query($conexion,$insert_registro);
        echo mysqli_error($conexion); 
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        

        $consulta="SELECT * FROM registro WHERE (Nombre_Usuario = '$nombre')";
        mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
            ?>
   
                <tr>
                   
                    <td> <?php echo $mostrar['Fecha']?> </td>
                    <td> <?php echo $mostrar['Nombre_Usuario']?></td>
                
                </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que a `mysqli_fetch_array` le estás pasando un string y lo que tienes que pasarle es un mysqli_result, o sea, el resultado de ejecutar una query.

Quedaría así:

```
$consulta="SELECT * FROM registro WHERE (Nombre_Usuario = '$nombre')";
$RESULTADO = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($RESULTADO)){
 //Ejecutar tu código aquí
}
```

La variable RESULTADO donde se almacena el resultado de la query la escribí toda en mayúscula para que resalte y veas los cambios. Generalmente una variable no se declara de esa forma. Se ve feo.

Espero sirva :-)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me funciono super bien.

Comment: @ErickAravenaNarbona si esta respuesta satisface a tu pregunta deberias marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo vea y no quede pendiente para siempre. Para aprender a aceptar preguntas consulta este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), gracias.